# Switching between GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I need to find the GPS location of the place.

The `NETWORK_PROVIDER` is not accurate and `GPS_PROVIDER` works only when I am outside the building.

Can anyone tell me, how I can switch between these two providers.

If possible please attach code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This is a detailed article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) in the android documentation that gives a way to get the best performance out of an android GPS chipset.

Switching between location providers can be done using `requestLocationUpdates()` and `removeUpdates()`

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to go is to use the [getBestProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) method and let the network manager figure out which one fits your needs the best. If you scroll down to "Location" on [this link](http://www.damonkohler.com/2009/02/android-recipes.html) you can find some good sample code.

---

**Frank Maker**
[handycodeworks.com](http://www.handycodeworks.com)